# kotest spring jpa repository bean creation failing during unit test

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotest

I'm new to Kotlin and have a simple list application I'm working on.

- Spring Boot 3.2.1
- kotest 5.8.0
- kotest spring extension 1.1.3

Dependencies:

```
  implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
  implementation("jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api")
  implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
  implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:$springDocOpenApiStarterWebmvcUiVersion")
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
  //  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
  runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
  runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
  annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
  testImplementation("com.ninja-squad:springmockk:$springmockkVersion")
  testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core:$kotestVersion")
  testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-json:$kotestVersion")
  testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5:$kotestVersion")
  testImplementation("io.kotest.extensions:kotest-extensions-spring:$kotestExtensionsSpringVersion")
  //  testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
  testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
    exclude(group = "org.assertj", module = "assertj-core")
    exclude(group = "org.hamcrest", module = "hamcrest")
    exclude(group = "org.mockito", module = "mockito-core")
    exclude(group = "org.mockito", module = "mockito-junit-jupiter")
  }
```

I'm writing some basic unit tests using kotest and the kotest spring extension.

However I have an error when trying to have a spring jpa (or crudrepository) bean created in the test context.

This *only* happens so far with spring repository interface. Not with a simple @Component annotated class. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@Repository interface LrmListRepository : JpaRepository<LrmList, Long>
```

Test Class:

```
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.WordSpec
import io.kotest.extensions.spring.SpringExtension
import net.flyingfishflash.loremlist.domain.lrmlist.data.LrmListRepository
import net.flyingfishflash.loremlist.domain.lrmlist.exceptions.ListNotFoundException
import org.junit.jupiter.api.assertThrows
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration

@ContextConfiguration(classes = [LrmListRepository::class])
class LrmListControllerTests(repository: LrmListRepository) : WordSpec() {
  override fun extensions() = listOf(SpringExtension)

  init {
    "SpringExtension" should {
      "have autowired the repository" {
        assertThrows<ListNotFoundException> {
          repository.findById(1L)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The test class is based on the example here: https://kotest.io/docs/extensions/spring.html

This test fails to build with this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.test.context.aot.TestContextAotException: Failed to process test class [net.flyingfishflash.loremlist.domain.lrmlist.LrmListControllerTests] for AOT

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No constructor or factory method candidate found for Root bean: class [net.flyingfishflash.loremlist.domain.lrmlist.data.LrmListRepository]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodNames=null; destroyMethodNames=null and argument types []
```

Any insight would be much appreciated thank you!

Comment: If you add your resolution as an answer to your own question instead of as an edit within the question other people with the same problem will be able to see that this question has been answered more easily.

Answer (score 0):

## Resolution

I did finally get the controller tests working the way I wanted, using a combination of spring annotations/kotest/mockk.

Hopefully this example helps someone also sifting through the testing landscape in kotlin.

Controller Test Class:

```kotlin
package net.flyingfishflash.loremlist.domain.lrmlist

import com.ninjasquad.springmockk.MockkBean
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.WordSpec
import io.kotest.extensions.spring.SpringExtension
import io.mockk.clearMocks
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.verify
import net.flyingfishflash.loremlist.domain.lrmlist.data.LrmList
import net.flyingfishflash.loremlist.domain.lrmlist.exceptions.ListNotFoundException
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.get

@WebMvcTest(controllers = [LrmListController::class])
class LrmListControllerTests(mockMvc: MockMvc) : WordSpec() {
  override fun extensions() = listOf(SpringExtension)

  @MockkBean
  lateinit var lrmListService: LrmListService

  init {
    "get /lists/1" should {
      "return 404 when list is not found" {
        val id = 1L
        every { lrmListService.findByIdOrListNotFoundException(id) } throws(ListNotFoundException())
        mockMvc.get("/lists/$id").andExpect { status { isNotFound() } }
        verify(exactly = 1) { lrmListService.findByIdOrListNotFoundException(id) }
      }
      "return 200 when list is found" {
        val id = 1L
        every {
          lrmListService.findByIdOrListNotFoundException(id)
        } returns LrmList(name = "Lorem List Name", description = "Lorem List Description")
        mockMvc.get("/lists/$id").andExpect { status { isOk() } }
        verify(exactly = 1) { lrmListService.findByIdOrListNotFoundException(id) }
      }
    }

    afterTest {
      clearMocks(lrmListService)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice work! You can also inject the `MockkBean` in the constructor, but you need to annotate the param like `@field:MockkBean lrmListService`.

Note that you only need to manually add the `SpringExtension` if you have disabled autoscanning.